# How to convert integer value to minutes in java

Tags: java, duration

I'm getting integer value from db as example integer value = 47. But when I pass that value to front end I need to convert it as minutes.

My scenario is I have 4 steps each step I'm getting an integer value, and after getting integer values I get the SUM of that 4 values.  Then I have to convert that to minutes or hours.

```
Integer totalDuration = (engageDuration + evaluateDuration + explainDuration + extendDuration);
```

OutPut:-

```
"totalDuration": 47
```

I need to convert this output for minutes and send it back to the front-end.

Comment: What does this integer value represent - seconds, milliseconds, something else?

Comment: Not mentioning the unit of the `totalDuration` makes this more a guessing game than an actual question.

Comment: totalDuration = 47 I'm considering as a minuets. yes you are right i need to give it like this way (47: - > 0:47).  if "totalDuration" greater than 60 i have to convert it to hours right?

Comment: @david_23 put this information into your question. You can still edit it.

Answer (score 2):

There's `java.time.Duration` and depending on the unit of your `totalDuration`, you could simply build up a `Duration` based on that value and then convert to minutes.

Let's assume `totalDuration` is a value of seconds. You could write the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example values
    int engageDuration = 1200;
    int evaluateDuration = 320;
    int explainDuration = 1200;
    int extendDuration = 100;
    // your summming operation
    int totalDuration = (engageDuration 
                        + evaluateDuration 
                        + explainDuration
                        + extendDuration);
    // THE IMPORTANT PART: making it a Duration of seconds
    Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(totalDuration);
    // print the amount of seconds
    System.out.println("Total duration: " + totalDuration + "s");
    // print the amount of full minutes and remaining seconds
    System.out.println(String.format("Total duration: %d minutes %d seconds",
                                    duration.toMinutesPart(),
                                    duration.toSecondsPart()));
}
```

Output:

```
Total duration: 2820s
Total duration: 47 minutes 0 seconds
```

Note: The methods `toMinutesPart()` and `toSecondsPart()` were added with Java 9. They are equivalent to calculating remaining units by `% 60`. That means you'll have to write `duration.toMinutes() % 60` if you want the returned minutes to be less than 60 (remaining ones apart from those forming whole hours).

Comment: Thanks for showing the OP the use of modern date-time API! Change  `duration.toMinutes()` to `duration.toMinutes() % 60`. A better way is to use just Java-9 API instead of mixing the Java-8 and Java-9 APIs. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65531362/10819573 for detailed formatting.

Comment: Good point, @ArvindKumarAvinash, thanks! I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Does the integer represent days?

**days to minutes**

```
minutes = days * 24 *60
```

**days to hours**

```
minutes = days * 24
```

If the integer doesn't represent days, then please comment it.

Comment: no the interger value doesn't represent days, its like a duration. but it saved as a integer value

Comment: Duration is represented as years, months, days, minutes or something.
Please specify it.

Comment: Isn't duration also expressed in parsecs? ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you need an Integer duration of an hour and minutes like 00:00

```
long miliSeconds=durection*60*100;
String formatDuration = DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(miliSeconds, "HH:mm", true);
```

if you are using  **DurationFormatUtils** then you need to add a dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below example of the main class:

```
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DurationFormatUtils;
    
    public class DurationExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            long duration=47*60*1000;
            String formatDuration = DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(duration, "HH:mm", true);
            System.out.println(formatDuration);
        }
    }
```